# Filter function - calling function on returned element?

Tags: jquery

I have a predefined set of elements on a page. I initially retrieve them via

```
scrollItems = $('div.topicrow-header')
```

At times I perform operations on this set. I use the `filter` method like so

```
scrollItems.filter('#' + curTopicId).addClass("stick");
```

I am fairly new to jQuery and Javascript, at times not really sure what the 'correct' way is to do certain things, and so I try and work my way through it. In this case, in addition to calling `addClass` on the element returned by `filter`, I want to perform other operations, like add a variable to the matched element, so that I have available, say, `scrollItems[idx].startTime`

How would I alter the above, so that in principle, I can syntactically do

```
scrollItems.filter('#' + curTopicId).doStuff( function {
   addClass("stick");
   scrollItems[matched_index].somevar = someval;
})
```

Would I just do something like

```
matched = scrollItems.filter('#' + curTopicId);
if (matched.length() != 0 ) {
   matched.addClass("stick");
   idx = matched.index();
   matched[idx].somevar = someval;
}
```

Edit:

I ended up doing the following, and seems to work. Still curious if there is a more 'pro' way...

```
$.each(scrollItems, function( index, value ) {
    if (value.id === curTopicId) {
       $(value).addClass("stick");
       topic_times[index].startTime = Date.now() / 1000 | 0;
       cur_idx = index;
       return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function that will retrieve a "scrollItem" from its `id`, add a class and an attribute to this item :

```
function doStuff(id){
    let elem = $('div.topicrow-header').filter("#" + id);
    elem.addClass("stick");
    elem.prop("startTime", Date.now() / 1000 | 0);
}
```

And then call this function for your current topic id :

```
doStuff(curTopicId);
```

Comment: That makes sense. But I need to be able to index into the element set of scrolledItems later on, and I was trying to use current and previous index values, so I always know how to index into the scrollItems object, without having to always call jQuery to alter the custom params that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

In my eyes you went into same pitfall like me, when I faced to `filter()` at jQuery.

https://api.jquery.com/filter/ is the documentaion for this function. I spent at least two hours to understand this page. So what is your mistake, in my eyes?

The most important thing of `filter()` function is, it needs an handwritten business logic. This is in charge for "filtering" the items from passed list. The bussines logic expects an matched item to return it.

```
let scrollItems = $('div.topicrow-header');
let itemsListAftering = $(scrollItems).filter(
 if ($(this) put here your condition)
 {
   return $(this);
 } 
);
```

After that your new workingbase is `itemsListAftering`:

```
$(itemsListAftering).each(function(){
  $(this).addClass("stick");
  $(this).prop("startTime", Date.now() / 1000 | 0);
});
```

Maybe the syntax of second part is not correct, so feel free to correct it.